# Regex is not matching with ending xml tag.I want to perform certain validation over xml elements, but one of the condition is not being satisfied

Tags: regex, xml, validation, xsd

I have written the regex in the XSD for one of the XML element. The conditions are below: It shouldn't be empty or white space or the tag value should not contain the $ followed by an alphabets. Example:

```
1.<element>I am $A test</element>--- this is invalid.

2.<element>I am $a test</element>--- this is invalid.

3.<element></element>--- this is invalid.
4.<element>   </element>--- this is invalid.

5.<element>I am $123.0 test on 02/01/2018 ongoing </element>--- this is 
 valid.
6.<element>I am $123.0 test on 02/01/2018 ongoing 
  month for another year
  </element>--- this is valid.
7.<element>I am test</element>--- this is valid.
```

XSD:

For checking the said conditions I am using below regex. but that is not working for testcase no.6 .In testcase no.6 the endtag is starting in new line ,that's causing an issue.

```
<xs:element name="element" minOccurs="1">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="1" />
<xs:pattern value="([^$\s]*(\s*$\d[^$\s]*|\s+[^$\s]+)+|[^$\s]+ 
(\s*$\d[^$\s]*|\s+ 
[^$\s]*)*)" />
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

Could anybody help to correct the above regex.
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit here is disallowing a string containing '$' followed by an alphabetic. I haven't been able to come up with a way of doing that with a regular XSD pattern facet (which doesn't mean it's impossible, of course). It's easy enough in XSD 1.1 where you can use the XPath `matches()` function in an assertion to provide a "negative pattern":

```
<xs:assertion test="normalize-space($value) 
                    and not(matches($value, '\$[\p{L}]'))"/>
```

The `normalize-space()` call requires the string to contain at least one non-space character.